# ANDROID: How to put a delay after a button is pushed?

Tags: android, button

I have a button and when it is pressed it plays an audio file. I want to put a 5 second delay on the button so users wont mash the button and play the sound over and over. I guess what i really want it for the button to be disabled for 5 seconds after it is pushed. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: but a 5 second delay may give the user the impression of the app being non-responsive

Comment: In case the length of the audio changes, perhaps you could consider a callback on media player - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001497/calling-another-activity-when-mediaplayer-get-finished-playing - instead of calling the activity, you can just re-enable your button

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In your onClickListener for the button:

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);

Timer buttonTimer = new Timer();
buttonTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                myButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
}, 5000);
```

This will disable the button when clicked, and enable it again after 5 seconds.

If the click event is handled in a class that extends View rather than in an Activity do the same thing but replace `runOnUiThread` with `post`.

Answer (score 36):

You can disable your button, then use the [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method on your button.

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
myButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}, 5000);
```

This is similar to the Timer solution, but it might better handle configuration change (for example if the user rotate the phone)

Comment: I think its `new Handler().postDelayed..`

Comment: No need to create another `Handler` -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)

Answer (score 5):

Here you go.

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.click))
    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.click)).setEnabled(false);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.click))
                    .setEnabled(true);

            }
        }, 5000);

    }
});
```