# How can I make AI pressing buttons with delay?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have AI, he must press buttons with delay. I use thread.sleep / handler.postdelayed / empty animation / and other things, but it is not works or it is not what I need.

Example of scenario what I need:

1. Wait 1 sec;
2. Button.setSelected(true);
3. Wait 1 sec;
4. Button.setPressed(true);
5. AI_Logic();

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398104/android-how-to-put-a-delay-after-a-button-is-pushed

Comment: I put this in my code, but it is not any wait.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199191/how-to-set-delay-in-android-onclick-function

Comment: Little bit help,thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for testing purposes just use [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso). If you need it in application what problems did you encounter?

Comment: I believe this is not for testing purpose.

Comment: My problem is Wait function. I can't find satisfied solution :(