# Execute task after some seconds only once

Tags: java, android

I want to call one method after some seconds (i.e 2 seconds). I have tried handler class but the method gets called every 2 seconds :( It continuously calls afters every 2 seconds.

**I am using this code in `onCreate`.**

My code :

```
 final Handler handler1 = new Handler();
            handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getLocation();

                }
            }, 2000);
```

Then i tried a boolean variable for this :

```
boolean isFirst = true;

 if (isFirst) {
            final Handler handler1 = new Handler();
            handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getLocation();

                    isFirst = false;

                }
            }, 2000);
        }
```

*Note : I am implementing LocationListener. for getting a current location and after getting a location calling a async task.*

Please give any suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13398166/3395198

Comment: You need to use shared preference for `isFirst` because isFirst will get initialize again inside `onCreate`

Comment: I am using this code in onCreate. i want show data when activity get loaded. Sorry i forget to mention.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya this link is not working in my case. same output

Comment: 2000 is 2 second i think... not 200

Comment: @Sam. thank you. but it's just an example not real one. I just want to stop this loop

Comment: @AkshayKatariya Can you provide answer accordingly your comment?

Comment: @Annie have you tried `handler1.removeCallbacks(runnable);` (make runnable object as `Runnable runnable = new Runnable();`

Comment: @Sam. Sorry i am not getting where to write these two lines?

Comment: after calling your handler.. it will stop your runnable method.

Comment: @Sam. yes i understand the purpose but where to write `Runnable runnable = new Runnable();` ? and `handler1.removeCallbacks(runnable);` after handler may be right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171055/discussion-between-sam-and-annie).

Comment: See the below code I given.You should not use that kind of timer/loop for location call back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below code :

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 2;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 2;
    Button btnFusedLocation;
    TextView tvLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    String mLastUpdateTime;

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ...............................");
        //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Log.d(TAG, "UI update initiated .............");
        if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
            String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
            String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
            tvLocation.setText("At Time: " + mLastUpdateTime + "\n" +
                    "Latitude: " + lat + "\n" +
                    "Longitude: " + lng + "\n" +
                    "Accuracy: " + mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy() + "\n" +
                    "Provider: " + mCurrentLocation.getProvider());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "location is null ...............");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want a location in oncreate not on any button click.. should i use this directly without button click?

Comment: getting error in line `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);` and in `mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();` and ` PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);`

Comment: Error:(536, 80) error: no suitable method found for requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient,LocationRequest,DashboardActivity)
method FusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient,LocationRequest,LocationListener) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; DashboardActivity cannot be converted to LocationListener)
method FusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient,LocationRequest,PendingIntent) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; DashboardActivity cannot be converted to PendingIntent)

Comment: Google play services required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171061/discussion-between-koustuv-ganguly-and-annie).